# Which analogies can be used in a hyperbole?

Tags: expressions

I want to ask if we can use **any kind of analogies when using an hyperbole** in a sentence?
For example, are these acceptable examples of hyperbole?

1. He changed his decision faster than a pion could decay.
2. She reached the place faster than light could.
3. His screams echoed throughout India.
4. She was done even before an electron flipped its spin.

*Please feel free to edit the question to make it better and add/replace tags.*

Comment: I would like to understand the question better. Are you asking if it's all right to use any example whatsoever in a hyperbole? Are you asking what kinds of examples are acceptable to use in a hyperbole? Or are you asking to see examples of hyperbole?

Comment: @defectedWBC You ask "*can [we] use **any** kind of examples when using an hyperbole in a sentence?*" **1.** How do you feel about "*He changed his decision faster than something that changes its decision very quickly*"? **2**. "than a pion **could** decay." is poor because pions have no control over their decay. The usual verb form is the simple form.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Sorry for the confusion but I meant to ask the first question in your list, i.e.  **Whether it's all right to use any example whatsoever in a hyperbole?**. Should I edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Some metaphors sound pretentious, even ludicrous. Even Bertie Wooster wouldn't touch some incandescent potatoes with a 3-parsec-long bargepole.

Comment: This question is not about English per se. It can apply to any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using whatever examples you want to in hyperbole as long as they make sense. However, a key consideration is the audience you are writing for. A hyperbole about pions would not be very appropriate for the general public - most of us have never heard of pions. However, it would be useful if you were writing for a scientific community. Keep audience in mind any time you write; a bored or confused audience will eventually stop reading.

Comment: Are you suggesting that depending on the audience, all kinds of analogies are accepted?

Comment: Actually, expressions that don't make sense are often used for humorous effect.

Comment: Can you please elucidate upon your point @HotLicks

Comment: Yes, any analogy that makes sense and can be understood by most of your audience would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Using all the discussion carried out, I believe it is fair to say that ***any kind of analogy*** can be used in hyperbole, keeping in mind the **desired effect** (we want to produce upon the audience) and the **interest and knowledge** of the concerned audience.

Comment: Please be aware that unsupported answers, and especially "I agree with X's [y's, ...] unsupported answers/comments", are usually considered unacceptable on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

I believe as long as the audience can grasp the gist of the sentence it would work.

"I searched the whole internet to give you this example"